# beautiful soup 4 print soup.find_all error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to export the text from beautiful soup into a text file but it shows

```
"text_file2.write(important) 
TypeError: expected a character buffer object"
```

This is my code

```
important=soup.find_all("tr", class_="accList")

with open("important.txt","w") as text_file2:
    text_file2.write(important)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The error has it all `expected a character buffer object` . `important` is an object which is not character buffer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start):

```
soup.find_all('a')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

So, `soup.find_all` returns a `list`, but you need a string (a character buffer object).

Try the following:

```
with open("important.txt","w") as text_file2:
    for x in important:
        text_file2.write(str(x)+'\n')
```

Comment: thanks. it returns    " text_file2.write(x+'\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'str' " does it mean that my soup.find_all returns a tag?

Comment: @user3396218, please reload the page: I've made an edit to my post.

Comment: thanks. managed to print out the text file. but nothing was inside. I think it might be due to my error in getting the data using beautiful soup. now i'm going to solve that one. thanks again!

Comment: @user3396218, try to print the `important` variable's value. If it's empty then the file'll be empty too